# kdb simple table join unexpected result

Tags: join, kdb, q-lang

I am trying out the example on how to join two tables found at http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#join

The example shows:

```
 t:([]a:1 2 3;b:`a`b`c)
 r:([]c:10 20 30;d:1.2 3.4 5.6)
 show t,`r
```

with this as the result:

```
     a b c  d
     ----------
     1 a 10 1.2
     2 b 20 3.4
     3 c 30 5.6
```

However, when I try it in my q console, I am getting this result:

```
   q)t,`r
   `a`b!(1;`a)
   `a`b!(2;`b)
   `a`b!(3;`c)
   `r
```

Can someone please explain what is happening, and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a tick ('), not a backtick (`)

So it should be

```
t,'r
```

not

```
t,`r
```

Comment: To elaborate further, you were appending the symbol `r to a table (list of dictionaries) which resulted in a general/mixed/non-uniform list. Same would occur if you tried t,2 for example.

Comment: Ah, such an easy mistake to make.  I am so used to using the backtick, I didn't even consider it might not be used in this case.  Thank you very much!